# StartAppAd.showSlider set to right side

Tags: android, slider, startapp

i am implementing **StartApp** ads in my android app, in which i am following this integration guide: `https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation#step8`

but the problem is the slider is always open from left side, but i want it to open from right side.

so how to set **StartApp** slider ads to right side.

Answer (score 0):

I asked them and that feature is not yet supported by them. So you just can't do that.